# Do Scalatests run in parallel by default under Gradle?

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest

We have tests written in Scala using Scalatest and JUnit4. The tests are annotated with `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])`. We're using Gradle `4.2.x` and I'd like to know, if the Scala tests are executing in parallel by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for parallel running you will need to add something like this to your test in build.gradle

```
test {    
      maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1      
    }
```